# Start SQL job as soon as it is deployed

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-job

I have created an SSIS package using Bids 2008 and configured the job to execute the package once a week on Friday. I would like to know will the job run as soon as it is deployed on any day for the first time. I need it to run the first time. Is it manual process

Answer (score 1):

No, job will not run as soon as it's been deployed. It will only run on specified time. You can try this by creating a package and setting up a job to call package and check whether it runs in development environment.

Comment: So I guess the answer is it will have to manually run in SSMS

Comment: If you want Job to run at other time than specified then yes `Manually`.